# Orientdb SubQuery Max Date

Tags: subquery, orientdb, graph-databases

I have searched for this and am not having much luck. I have a graph database setup in OrientDb (3.0.2) and am having some issues with subquerys. I would be able to write this easily in a classic relational database. I have played around with LET and $parent/$children but these concepts are still a bit confusing.

**Three Vertexes:** Entity <- Inspection -> Violations

I would like the last Inspection (date) for each Entity and to know how many Violations there were associated with that Inspection.

I know how to pull the number of Violations for each Inspection (size() of edges). I also know how to pull the max Inspection date for each entity but combining these two has been a struggle. Any thoughts? Thank you!

**Update:** I think I am getting closer but still not sure how to do an "inner" join. Not sure if I totally understand how the $parent/$current variables work. ***This query does not work***

```
SELECT
    entityId
    ,$a.num_violations
    ,max(Date) as mDate
FROM (
    SELECT
        @rid AS entityId
        ,in('COMPLETED_AT').Date as Date
    FROM Entity
    unwind Date
)
let $a = (
  SELECT
    Date
    ,out('FOUND_DURING').size() as num_violations
  FROM Inspection
  WHERE $parent.mDate = Date
  AND $parent.entityId in out('COMPLETED_AT').@rid
)
GROUP BY entityId
    ,$a.num_violations
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select expand($c)
let $a = (select date, out("link")[@class="Violations"].size() as num_violations from Inspection),
$b = (select name, max(date) as max_date from (select name, in("link").date as date from Entity unwind date) group by name),
$c = unionAll($a, $b)
```

this is what you get:

```
+----+-------------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+
|#   |date               |num_violations|name      |max_date           |
+----+-------------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+
|0   |2018-08-31 00:00:00|1             |          |                   |
|1   |2018-08-30 00:00:00|2             |          |                   |
|2   |2018-08-29 00:00:00|1             |          |                   |
|3   |                   |              |entity_001|2018-08-31 00:00:00|
|4   |                   |              |entity_002|2018-08-29 00:00:00|
+----+-------------------+--------------+----------+-------------------+
```

**UPDATE**

```
select expand($c)
let $a = (select name as entity_name, max(date) as max_date from (select name, in("link").date as date from Entity unwind date) group by name),
$b = (select out("link")[@class="Violations"].size() as num_violations from Inspection),
$c = unionAll($a, $b)


+----+-----------+-------------------+--------------+
|#   |entity_name|max_date           |num_violations|
+----+-----------+-------------------+--------------+
|0   |entity_001 |2018-08-31 00:00:00|              |
|1   |entity_002 |2018-08-29 00:00:00|              |
|2   |           |                   |1             |
|3   |           |                   |2             |
|4   |           |                   |1             |
+----+-----------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: First off, thank you for the quick reply Michela. This example alone has helped me understand the LET structure better so if anything, this has been successful. However, the result did not turn out as expected - even though I would think it would show up as your example. The output only shows the information from $a and nothing from $b even though both LET statements work. Any thoughts? Looks like something may be off with the unionall() function. Also, is there a way to structure the output to show just three columns: Entity Name, Last Inspection Date, and Number of Violations? Thanks!

Comment: @akizze01 I updated my answer, the query now shows 3 columns only.

Comment: Thanks again Michela. I guess I am still confused why we can't put the results for each entity all on one line? For instance, I am looking for entity_001, 2018-08-31, and 1 on the same row. Otherwise, how would I know which num_violations is associated with each entity? Would it be easier for me to have code that creates edges for the most recent Inspection and have this code delete/create edges as new inspections are added? Thanks!

Comment: @akizze01 Did you ever figure this one out? I ask because I'm facing something similar...